# Powershell Nested objects filtering empty values

Tags: arrays, powershell, filtering

The following workflow generates a list of all the printers on a server:

```
Workflow Get-PrintersInstalledHC {
    Param (
        [String[]]$Servers
    )
    Foreach -Parallel ($S in $Servers) {
        InlineScript {
            $S = $Using:S
            Write-Verbose "Server: $S"

            Try {
                if ($Printers = Get-Printer -ComputerName $S -Full -EA Stop) {
                    $Params = @{
                        ComputerName = $S
                        Property     = '*'
                        ErrorAction  = 'Stop'
                    } 
                    $Config = Get-CimInstance @Params -ClassName Win32_PrinterConfiguration
                    $Ports = Get-CimInstance @Params -ClassName Win32_TCPIPPrinterPort

                    Foreach ($P in $Printers) {
                        Write-Verbose "Printer: $($P.Name)"
                        Foreach($C in $Config) {
                            if ($P.Name -eq $C.Name) {
                                $PortHostAddress = $Ports | Where {$_.Name -eq $P.PortName} | 
                                                        Select -ExpandProperty HostAddress
                                $Prop = @{
                                    PortHostAddress     = $PortHostAddress
                                    DriverVersion       = $C.DriverVersion
                                    Collate             = $C.Collate
                                    Color               = $C.Color
                                    Copies              = $C.Copies
                                    Duplex              = $C.Duplex
                                    PaperSize           = $C.PaperSize
                                    Orientation         = $C.Orientation
                                    PrintQuality        = $C.PrintQuality
                                    MediaType           = $C.MediaType
                                    DitherType          = $C.DitherType
                                    RetrievalDate       = (Get-Date -Format 'dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm')
                                }
                                $P | Add-Member -NotePropertyMembers $Prop -TypeName NoteProperty
                                Break
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    [PSCustomObject]@{
                        ComputerName   = $S
                        ComputerStatus = 'Ok'
                        RetrievalDate  = (Get-Date -Format 'dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm')
                        Printers       = $Printers
                    }
                }
            }
            Catch {
                if (Test-Connection $S -Count 2 -EA Ignore) {
                    [PSCustomObject]@{
                        ComputerName   = $S
                        ComputerStatus = "ERROR: $($Error[0].Exception.Message)" 
                        RetrievalDate  = (Get-Date -Format 'dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm')
                        Printers       = $null
                    }
                }
                else {
                    [PSCustomObject]@{
                        ComputerName   = $S
                        ComputerStatus = 'Offline'
                        RetrievalDate  = (Get-Date -Format 'dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm')
                        Printers       = $null
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
$Printers = Get-PrintersInstalledHC Server1
```

What I am having trouble with is filtering out the empty values in `$Printers.Printers.PortHostAddress`. As discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17704779/empty-value-powershell-array) it should suffice to just do:

```
$Printers.Printers.PortHostAddress | where {$_} | % -Begin{$i = 0} -Process{$i; $_; $i++}
```

Other attempts are not working either, as:

```
$Printers.Printers.PortHostAddress | where {$_ -ne $null} | % -Begin{$i = 0} -Process{$i; $_; $i++}
$Printers.Printers.PortHostAddress | where {$_ -ne ''} | % -Begin{$i = 0} -Process{$i; $_; $i++}
```

Unfortunately, when the printer's name is for example `Microsoft XPS Document Writer` and the value in `PortHostAddress` stays empty, it's still not filtered out of the list as you can see by the numbers.

Is there another way to filter out the `PortHostAddress` when there is no value?

Comment: Very strange that it's not by default `$Null`. Fixed it with a workaround in the `Workflow` by changing it to `PortHostAddress     = if ($PortHostAddress) {$PortHostAddress} else {$null}`. Don't know if this is the clean way to do it, but it works.

Comment: I think the reason null is not matching is because there is an _empty_ object there with no note properties. Check the return type of portaddress. Its `System.Management.Automation.PSCustomObject`. That is why your check in comments is working and null is not.

Comment: What do you get with `($_ -as [string]) -ne ''`?

Comment: Same problem i'm afraid.

Comment: Can you do the reverse and test for length >=1